# An input encoding problem

Tags: miktex, input-encodings, winedt

I have two similar (as far as I can say) installations of MikTex 2.9+Winedt 10.3 on two Windows 10 machines. When I LaTex a particular file on one machine, it compiles with no problem. On the other machine, however, it gives me the following error message:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.129 Lenstra, and Lovász
                          known as the LLL algorithm for lattice reduction
? 

! Undefined control sequence.
```

The problem seems to be the encoding of "Lovász" but I do not know how to solve it. I have looked at the input encoding documentation but it did not help. I am sure that the LaTeX files are exactly the same, one file on a Google drive. When I look at the bottom of Winedt windows on both machines, bot show UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Can you confirm that the files are indeed encoded in UTF-8 independently with another editor? (Notepad++ comes to mind? Check that the `á` is properly displayed there.)

Comment: Can you give a minimal example that I compile on my computer under MikTeX and Windows 10?

Comment: A short-term fix (not a full solution!): Replace all instances of `Lovász` with `Lov{\'a}sz`.

Comment: If the linebreak in the error is where you show the problem is not the accented a but bad bytes at the space.

Comment: To check on David's suspicion copy and paste the entire line `Lenstra, and Lovász ...` from your `.tex` file into https://w3c.github.io/xml-entities/unicode-names.html. If the output mentions any weird characters those could be the reason for the error.

Comment: The root file was UTF-8 encoded but the child file was APC encoded. I used @Mico's suggestion to solve the problem. I still do not know how to save a file with UTF-8 encoding. Anyway, I consider my problem solved by using Mico's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The root file was UTF-8 encoded but the child file was APC encoded. I used @Mico's suggestion to solve the problem. I still do not know how to save a file with UTF-8 encoding. Anyway, I consider my problem solved by using Mico's suggestion.